# Textfield materialui

Tags: reactjs

tengo un error en el textfield (adjunto foto) donde en label queda por debajo del outline[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca abajo dejo como esta implementado el codigo

```js
<Controller
                  name='email'
                  control={control}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => (
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      label='Correo Electrónico'
                      value={value}
                      onBlur={onBlur}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      error={Boolean(errors.email)}
                      placeholder='admin@estoesapp.com'
                    />
                  )}
                />
```